# Lights Out in Python- How to Get Adjacent Tiles in a one-dimensional array?

Tags: python, list, pygame

My next python project is Lights Out using python and pygame. I need some help with beginning. I have a system that creates an empty board, then creates 25 index positions, and sets them all to false except a few, like so:

```
board = []
for x in range(0, 25):
    board.append(False)
for x in range(0, random.randint(3,8)):
    board[x] = True
random.shuffle(board)
```

Then the program can use the list to read the state for rectangles in a 5x5 grid. But how do I find adjacent tiles?

Lights out consists of a grid of tiles that can be on or off, similar to many cellular animations. A board is typically 5x5, and a certain number of tiles start off as "on". When a player clicks a tile, the state of the tile flips, as well as all the orthogonally adjacent tiles.

To get adjacent tiles, should I make a dictionary with numbers 0 through 24 that correspond to tiles they're next to? There must be a simpler way. Research turned up nothing concerning 1D arrays, only 2D arrays. Modeling [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/recreational-math/puzzles/lights-puzzles/e/lights-puzzles-3).

Comment: It's probably easiest to start by making a 2-D board instead of a 1-D board.

Comment: Reason for down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a board of size MXM we can write this short algorithm:

```
def getIndexOfNeighoringTiles(i):
    neighbors = []
    if (i % M != 0):
        neighbors.append(i-1)
    if (i % M != (M-1)):
        neighbors.append(i+1)
    if (i / M != 0):
        neighbors.append(i-M)
    if (i / M != (M-1)):
        neighbors.append(i+M)
    return neighbors
```

To explain a bit, we have 4 edge cases where we want to exclude certain indexes.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. The last sentence after the code was very helpful. I'm relatively new to programming, forgive if the question was obvious, I couldn't find anything.